# How to make button in default state in ionic?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have this app which requires to create a survey page. Each survey questions have **Yes** and **No** button as response of the user.

Since I am new in using Ionic, my issue is, after building the code, and time to check my output. One of the button is already on clicked state, as you can see in the image below. That is the current situation once I run my app. Which is, the button should be unclick and with white background. Hope you can help me since I am still confuse it using Ionic.

[image: image below]

Here are my codes I used:

**.html -edited**

```
 <ion-row>
    <ion-col size-md = "6">
      <ion-button (click)="onYesQ1()" [ngClass]="enoughTime ==='Yes' ?'btn-pressed':'btn-unpressed'"  [class]="btn-pressed" fill = "clear">
        <div class = "parentElement">  
      <img src = "{{myYesImage|staticpath}}"/>
    <br><br><p class = "btn-work"><b>Yes</b></p>
        </div>
      </ion-button>
      <ion-button (click)="onNoQ1()" [ngClass]="enoughTime ==='No' ?'btn-pressed':'btn-unpressed'" class="" fill = "clear">
        <div class = "parentElement">
         <img src = "{{myNoImage|staticpath}}"/>
         <br><br><p class = "btn-work"><b>No</b></p>
        </div>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

**.scss**

```
.btn-pressed{
vertical-align: middle;
width: 126px;
height: 90px;
left: 35.7px;
background: #0E82C1;
border: 1px solid #979797;
box-sizing: border-box;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
border-radius: 23px;
color: white;

}

.btn-unpressed {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 126px;
  height: 90px;
  left: 35.7px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0px 10px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  }
```

**.ts -edited**

```
        @Input() enoughTime : string = "";
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify your code bit like mentioned below. its not a issue with ionic. Issue is with your logic.

**.ts file**

```
@Input() enoughTime : string = "";
```

**.html file**

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col size-md = "6">
      <ion-button (click)="onYesQ1()" [ngClass]="enoughTime ==='Yes' ?'btn-pressed':'btn-unpressed'"  [class]="btn-pressed" fill = "clear">
        <div class = "parentElement">  
      <img src = "{{myYesImage|staticpath}}"/>
    <br><br><p class = "btn-work"><b>Yes</b></p>
        </div>
      </ion-button>
      <ion-button (click)="onNoQ1()" [ngClass]="enoughTime ==='No' ?'btn-pressed':'btn-unpressed'" class="" fill = "clear">
        <div class = "parentElement">
         <img src = "{{myNoImage|staticpath}}"/>
         <br><br><p class = "btn-work"><b>No</b></p>
        </div>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

Comment: `<ion-button *ngIf="enoughTime=='Yes'" (click)="onYesQ1()"  class = activated class="btn-pressed" fill = "clear">` like this?

Comment: You have added two class .. you can combine both like ` class="activated btn-pressd active" `

Comment: I tried this `<ion-button *ngIf="enoughTime=='Yes'" (click)="onYesQ1()" class="activated btn-pressed active" fill = "clear">` and `<ion-button *ngIf="enoughTime=='Yes'" (click)="onYesQ1()" class="activated btn-pressed" fill = "clear">` but still same issue occur. After I run the app, the button is still not in white background

Comment: My bad I got you wrong. I have update my code please use the updated code and try again

Comment: Hi! I am now applying your solution, but I encountered error *Identifier 'pressed' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member ng*, in `[class]="btn-pressed` in this line of code `<ion-button (click)="onYesQ1()" [ngClass]="enoughTime ==='Yes' ?'btn-pressed':'btn-unpressed'"  [class]="btn-pressed" fill = "clear">`. Thank you

Comment: `[ngClass]="btn-pressed"` is this the solution for the error I encountered above comment?

Comment: nope this is apply btn-pressed class to button .

Comment: can you please update your code with new change so that i can look into this and highlight the error you are getting

Comment: ooh my bad .. you can remove that ` [class]="btn-pressed"`  its not useful

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is now working :)

Comment: Please Accept this answer too .. it will help me in my ranking ..